# Dedekind(?) representation lemma on posets?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, order-theory

Here's an easy lemma:

*Any poset $(S, \preceq)$ is order-isomorphic to a subset of the powerset $\mathcal{P}(S)$ ordered by set-inclusion.*

I seem to recall having seen this attributed to Dedekind.

Am I right that Dedekind proves this little result? And if so, where does he do it?

Comment: You might want to ask this at [History of Science and Math S.E.](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try there too --- I didn't know about that S.E.!

Comment: It's very recent, it's still a beta. I also suggest that you add link each question to each other so the answers reach people on both sites.

Comment: Amusing, this is an exercise I am giving for my students to submit next week. I just posted it on the course website an hour ago! :-)

Comment: Perhaps it is named for Dedekind in recognition of his work on Dedekind cuts?

Comment: Please, see [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/500/did-dedekind-prove-this-lemma-about-posets-or-an-equivalent)

Comment: @Mauro: You might add that Dedekind’s *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen* is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/wassindundwasso00dedegoog).